# How to change iframe src use angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<iframe src="{{url}}" width="300" height="600">
                <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
            </iframe>
```

How to change iframe src

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need also `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl` or it won't open the website inside the iframe:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/0mjkyke2/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dummy">
    <button ng-click="changeIt()">Change it</button>
    <iframe ng-src="{{url}}" width="300" height="600"></iframe>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('dummy', ['$scope', '$sce', function ($scope, $sce) {

    $scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://www.angularjs.org');

    $scope.changeIt = function () {
        $scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial');
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I think this should be considered as the correct answer

Answer (score 11):

Why don't you change the source to ng-src. That way, you may link the src to a variable, and change it as follows:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{url}}">  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p> </iframe>
```

Comment: works only for image. need to use $sce.trustAsResourceUrl

Comment: @KamalKumar Yeah you need to use $sce but without ng-src you will get a bunch of console errors and bad requests.