# Embed Youtube Video not showing when using Angularjs expression link?

Tags: html, angularjs

```
         <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns" ng-if="video">
            Testing video link: https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{video}}
                <div class="h_iframe">
                    <iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{video}}?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
        </div>
```

I cannot display the embed youtube video on my webpage? I was able to display the Testing video link with valid URL.

In the iframe, my video does not show up. But if I change my src code ('"https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{video}}?rel=0"') to a direct link without the expression, it works. How do i get this to work with using angularjs express?

EDIT:
Made some changes from Jane.

```
<div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns" ng-if="video">
                Testing video link: https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{video}}
                    <div class="h_iframe">
                        <iframe width="854" height="480" ng- src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{video}}?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Changed from src to ng-src. 
Now the problem:
 my Testing video link: https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{video}} doesn't show up.
My video doesnt show up.

SOLVED:
A linked from Jane in comment has lead to the solution. Thanks.

Comment: what does {{video}} output?

Comment: the youtube video ID.

Comment: So if my {{video}} was set on the controller to '33Rs8Swa984'. it will print out Testing video link: https://www.youtube.com/embed/33Rs8Swa984

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change iframe src use angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309183/how-to-change-iframe-src-use-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing a `src` instead of an `ng-src` since you are trying to input some angular into the src..

This should work for you, I think:

```
<iframe width="854" height="480" ng-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{video}}?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You can read more about `ng-src` here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: @Pop-A-Stash {{video}} is a string that get pulled from controller. Its a youtube ID. for example, video can be '33Rs8Swa984'. I have changed to ng-src and it still won't work on my situation